# adding multiple objects to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to add all of the user input I just received and put it all into one array position.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int cit = 0;

//cit = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

/*if statement to ensure a value greater than 0 and less than or equal to 50 is
 * entered.
 */
//System.out.println(cit);
System.out.println("Welcome to OswegoNote - your friendly Citation Manager.");
boolean accepted = false;
Index citationIndex;
 Citation currentCitation;
 while (!accepted) {
    System.out.println("How many citations would you like to store today? (between 0 and 50):");
    cit = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    int citcounter = cit;
    if (cit <= 50) {

        if (cit > 0) {
            accepted = true;
            citationIndex = new Index(cit);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: please enter a number between 0 and 50.");
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: please enter a number between 0 and 50.");
    }//end if <=50

}//end while loop



for (int i = 0; i < cit; i++) {

    currentCitation = new Citation("");
    currentCitation.updateId(i);

    System.out.println("Please enter publication name (or 'quit' to quit):");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    currentCitation.setName(name);


    System.out.println("Please enter the date of publication (in mm/dd/yyyy format) (or 'quit' to quit):");
    String pubDate = sc.nextLine();
    currentCitation.setDateOfPublication(pubDate);



    //while (accepted = true) {
    System.out.println("How many authors are there? (max 3):");
    int numAuthors = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    //currentCitation.numOfAuthors = numAuthors;
    if (numAuthors <= 3 && numAuthors > 0) {
        for (int a = 0; a < numAuthors; a++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name of author #" + (a+1) + ". (FirstName MI. LastName) (or 'quit' to quit):");
            String authorName = sc.nextLine();
            currentCitation.addAuthor(authorName);
        }
        accepted = false;
        //break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number between 0 and 3.");
    } //end if
    //}



    System.out.println("Where was it published? (or 'quit' to quit):");
    String pubPlace = sc.nextLine();
    currentCitation.setWherePublisher(pubPlace);

    System.out.println("What is the publisher's name? (or 'quit' to quit):");
    String publisher = sc.nextLine();
    currentCitation.setPublisher(publisher);

    //while (accepted = true) {
    System.out.println("How many keywords would you like to add?(max 5) (or 'quit' to quit):");
    int numKeywords = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    if (numKeywords <= 5 && numKeywords > 0) {
        for (int k = 0; k < numKeywords; k++) {
            System.out.println("Enter keyword #" + (k+1) + ". (or 'quit' to quit)");
            String keyW = sc.nextLine();

            currentCitation.addKeyword(keyW);
        }
        accepted = false;
        //break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number between 0 and 5.");
    } //end if
    //}

    System.out.println("This is your Citation:");
    System.out.println("Name: " + currentCitation.getName());
    System.out.print("Author(s): ");

    for (int s = 0; s <= numAuthors - 1; s++) {
        if ((numAuthors - 1) > s) {
        System.out.print(currentCitation.authors[s] + ", ");
    } else {
            System.out.println(currentCitation.authors[s]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Date of Publication: " + currentCitation.getDateOfPublication());
    System.out.println("Name of Publisher: " + currentCitation.getPublisher());
    System.out.println("Publication Place: " + currentCitation.getWherePublisher());

    System.out.print("Keywords: ");
    for (int s = 0; s <= numKeywords - 1; s++) {
        if ((numKeywords - 1) > s) {
            System.out.print(currentCitation.keywords[s] + ", ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(currentCitation.keywords[s]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to save this? (yes or no or 'quit' to quit):");
    String answer = sc.nextLine();
    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

    } else { 
        citationIndex[i] = {currentCitation.authors, currentCitation.keywords, currentCitation.ID, currentCitation.dateOfPublication, currentCitation.name, currentCitation.publisher, currentCitation.wherePublisher};
    }

}// end for
```

Sorry for the entire main method. I'm not very good at Java so I don't really know how I could describe my situation.

Comment: I'm trying to add all of the input into the the citationIndex[].

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having in a bit more detail?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Obviously nobody will read your entire code without knowing what exactly to look for.

Comment: Could you please provide an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) ?! It will help us to answer your question, thus helping you having a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array and then add multiple items to it via [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

If the items you want to add to it are not already in a collection, put them in one first:

`mylist.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));`

Or you can add them one at a time:

```
mylist.add(1);
mylist.add(2);
mylist.add(3);
```

DISCLAIMER: I only browsed your code because I didn't want to read it. I'm mostly answering based on your question's title.

Comment: We are not allowed to use ArrayList for this assignment.

Comment: What the assignment does is it takes user input (name of a book, publisher, publish date, keywords, ID#, etc.) and after we get all of the input we are supposed to put it into an array that contains all of the citation data

Comment: takes two arrays in the process of gathering the information, keywords [] and authors [].

Comment: Then state all such things in your question, not here.

Comment: SO is not a place where you ask people to do your homework... You should show us what is going wrong in your program, not just copy paste your entire code. Where are you stuck ? @user2800960